# reduce and do.call work differently for 1-element list

Tags: r, purrr

I use map/reduce on a vector that sometimes has only one element. It returns a numeric vector instead of a matrix. do.call works as expected

```
test1 <- 1
map_l1 <- map(test1, ~ .x*c(1,2,3))
r1 <- reduce(map_l1, rbind)
r1
d1 <- do.call("rbind", map_l1)
d1
```

map/reduce on a vector with more than one element works as expected

```
test2 <- c(1,2)
map_l2 <- map(test2, ~ .x*c(1,2,3))
r2 <- reduce(map_l2, rbind)
r2
d2 <- do.call("rbind", map_l2)
d2
```

As I do not know a-priori the size of the initial vector I use do.call().
Is there a way to use reduce()?

Comment: Is there more context to what you're trying to do here?  Using `reduce()` is a terribly inefficient way to go about row binding the matrix.  `do.call()` is a much better option.

Comment: How about `dplyr`'s `bind_rows()`?

Comment: Or `data.table`s `rbindlist`.

Comment: Thanks for all responses, so I gather that this is not a bug but a feature ?? anyway was not aware to the efficiency aspect so I wil stick with do.call